# Capture GlassFish log file into SQL/JPA data base

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, java.util.logging

I need a little help getting started.  I have a new JSF-2 web application that I intend to deploy under GlassFish 3.1 (or higher).   Normally the server stores all its log files as text in one of its private directories, which also includes the logging I do with ether **System.println( .. )** or something like **java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger( ... )**

What I want to do is instead of those logging entries going to the text file, capture them and file them into my SQL data base.  I can then add table columns for timestamp and key values so it can be easily searched as part of the admin web page in the application, rather than having to go to the admin console for it.  It would be possible also to expose some of that data to users.

Can this be done and how?

Follow up question:  could this be done in a way that would be portable to Tomcat or another container?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write custom log handler. Custom log handler is a class that extends `java.util.logging.Handler`:

```
package test.stackoverflow;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
..
public class AlanHandler extends Handler {
..
        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {
              //CODE THAT STORES LOG RECORD INTO THE DATABASE
        }
}
```

Additionally, you will have to slightly change `logging.properties` file:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, test.stackoverflow.AlanHandler
```

Deploy JAR of AlanHandler on Glassfish (as a library), restart the server and that should do it.

Comment: This looks really simple.   I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: It is simple :) In older version of Glassfish (2.1) you had also something called 'management rules' where you could configure to catch certain log events (e.g. SEVERE). Together with custom MBeans, that was nice and useful tool, however it seems that they didn't have a time to implement it newer version (I read some thread on official GF site about it).